# Changing the order of two DIVs with float - IE bug

Tags: html, css, browser, css-float

I want to change the order of two DIVs with css-float. I don't want to/I can't change their order in HTML, because it's external data.
The following html does this in Firefox, but produces contrarious output in IE:

```
<div style="display:inline">Berta</div>
<div style="float:left; display:inline">Albert</div>
```

in Firefox:

AlbertBerta

in IE:

BertaAlbert

Question: Is there a way to get the Firefox-output also in IE?  My Example does this -- but only in Firefox, not in IE. Anyway thanks for the responses.

Comment: So you can change inline styles *in the HTML*, but not change the order of the `div`s, which are also *in the HTML*. That seems a bit odd.

Comment: `display:inline` has normally no effect in combination with `float:left` except in IE in some instances. Is the document in Standards or Quirks mode?

Answer (score 0):

First, use a valid doctype. You could stick with the time and use `<!DOCTYPE html>`.  And second, like @RoToRa commented, float and inline is not really nice.

Let them become block elements with `display: block;` (or maybe `inline-block`) and then change the floats. The first one to `right` and the second one to `left` (or vice versa). This even works in IE.

Answer (score -1):

```
<div style="float:left; display:inline">Albert</div>
<div style="display:inline">Berta</div>
```

This may work..
But there is no issue in IE9

Accept or vote up if it works

Comment: As the heading of my question says, I want to change the order of two divs with css-float. I don't want to/I can't change their order in HTML, because it's external data. My Example does this -- but only in Firefox, not in IE. Anyway thanks for the responses